# How to filter object's property by some criteria and have the remaining properties adapt

Tags: javascript

Supposing my object's properties are arrays, how do I filter by one of the properties and have all of the other properties adapt to its length?

Example object:

```
var activities = {
    start_date: [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
    average_speed: [10, 45, 34, 23, 65, 43, 11, 22, 55],
};
```

Returning a filtered object:

```
function filter(activities) {
    filtered = {
        start_date: activities.start_date.filter(date => date > 2006),
        average_speed: activities.average_speed,
    };
    return filtered
};
```

The  returned `filtered` object will have uneven arrays lengths, and I would like `filtered.average_speed` to contain only `[11, 22, 55]`.

Just like in Python I can leverage the Pandas `dataframe` object (however I do not want to use Javascript's dataframe libraries so as not to add another dependency):

```
import pandas

activities = pandas.DataFrame(some_data)

def filter(activities):
        selected = activities[activities['start_date'] > 2009]
    return selected
```

And the size of the dataframe will adapt to the size of `start_date` array/column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of every matching element in `start_date`, then use `.map` to create the associated array from both `start_date` and `average_speed`:

```js
var activities = {
  start_date: [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
  average_speed: [10, 45, 34, 23, 65, 43, 11, 22, 55],
};

function filter({ start_date, average_speed }) {
  const indicies = start_date.reduce((a, date, i) => {
    if (date > 2006) a.push(i);
    return a;
  }, []);
  return {
    start_date: indicies.map(i => start_date[i]),
    average_speed: indicies.map(i => average_speed[i])
  };
};
console.log(filter(activities));
```

This method is easily extensible to additional properties other than `average_speed`.

If you find yourself doing this sort of thing more than a bit, you might consider reorganizing your data to be an array of objects, instead of an object containing two separate arrays, eg:

```
var activities = [
  { start_date: 2001, average_speed: 10 },
  { start_date: 2002, average_speed: 145 },
  ...
```

Then, getting the filtered data is a single simple `.filter` away.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I especially love the suggestion to turn the data into an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If `start_date` is always in order you can use `.slice` to keep only the last *n* elements of the `average_speed` array and use the `get` keyword to self reference the objects own property `start_date`:

```js
var activities = {
  start_date: [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009],
  average_speed: [10, 45, 34, 23, 65, 43, 11, 22, 55],
};

function filter(activities) {
  filtered = {
    start_date: activities.start_date.filter(date => date > 2006),
    get average_speed() {return activities.average_speed.slice(-this.start_date.length)
    }
  };
  return filtered
};

console.log(filter(activities));
```

Comment: This will only work if the `start_date`s are always in order.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah I see now. My original understanding of OP's question was something a little different. I've amended my response now. Thanks